# How to make casino-like increment of a letter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, replace

I need to convert (when the user does something):

```
adcb
```

to (the next letter of every letter):

```
bedc
```

Currently I am just going with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and overwrite the character.

Remember the Pkmn Game Corner?

[image]

Wouldn't it be cool if we could simulate that movement of the character (in the pic, change from 7 to Pikachu)?

PS - I have no idea on how to approach this...

Comment: Maybe an array of options, generate a random number and loop through the array writing out/displaying the option (overwriting the old value) until you reach that random number? It's need some delay in there to make it visible, but other than that it's a pretty simple solution.

Comment: Oh @DBS you mean to do it in the traditional way, but just replacing the letter with random letters, in order to simulate the effect? Clever! I would be happy to accept such an answer! :) EDIT: The [fadein](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/) could probably help for that,

Comment: Does this need to be done inside a text input? Or is the output separate? (Animating things inside inputs could be a bit of a pain)

Comment: It's inside an `<h1>`, but make it wherever you prefer and I will get it from there to match my needs @DBS.

Comment: Do you mean you need `console.log("adcb".split("").map(function(x) { return String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0)+1);}).join(""));`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah that's pretty much what I am actually doing, but it happens out of nothing, I would like it to be more cool, more fancy, more funny. I got a [reason](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46056/please-help-me-create-a-puzzle-to-ask-a-girl-out). ;)

Comment: Could you not convert each letter to ascii code and +1 and convert back?

Comment: @Zinc to be honest I am not sure what you mean. However, if you have an idea and time to post an answer, I promise I will look it! ;)

Comment: @gsamaras - I know you have already accepted Alex's great answer but I added my answer anyway for your future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with CSS animations to move the letter around, updating the letter when it is not visible.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/ctuujz3j/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="reels">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>L</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>X</div>
</div>
<button id="slide">Slide</button>
```

CSS:

```
#reels > div {
  width: 20px;
  height:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:3px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#reels > div.reel-change {
  animation: slideReel 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slideReel {
  0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
  }
  49% {
      transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50% {
      transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  100 % {
      transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

#reels {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slide').click(function() {
    var delay = 0;
    $('#reels').children().each(function() {
        var reel = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
        $(reel).toggleClass("reel-change");
      }, delay);
      setTimeout(function() {
        changeLetter(reel);
      }, delay + 500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(reel).toggleClass("reel-change");
      }, delay + 1000);
      delay += 500;
    });
  });
});

function changeLetter(el) {
      el.innerHTML = incrementChar(el.innerHTML);
}

var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
function incrementChar(c) {
    var index = alphabet.indexOf(c);
    return alphabet[index + 1] || alphabet[0];
}
```

Edit: Seeing as it's a good reason for doing it based on your above comments, I made it a bit prettier!!

https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/ctuujz3j/2/

Comment: I will choose another answer of yours I like and upvote, as a thank you for understanding my super duper reason! Fingers crossed Alex, fingers crossed... :)

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this is what you can do...

```
var strMsg = 'abcdef';
var tmpStr = '';

function nextLetter(letter) {
    var charCode = letter.charCodeAt(0);
    return String.fromCharCode((charCode - 96) % 26 + 97)
}

for(var i=0; i < strMsg.length; i++) {
  tmpStr += nextLetter(strMsg[i]);
}

console.log(tmpStr); // bcdefg
```